# Vaadin 23 Won't Build with Gradle Due to Licensing

Tags: gradle, vaadin23

Trying to build Vaadin 23 SpringBoot app with Gradle in production mode. Fails with:

gradlew build

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':my_webapp:vaadinBuildFrontend'.
  > The provided license key does not allow usage of vaadin-board 23.3.5. Check that the license has not expired and that the product you are trying to use does not require another type of subscription.

Builds with Maven just fine.

I had to manually exclude every commercial component in the Gradle build.  Surely there must be a better way, or is this a bug in Vaadin 23?

```
    implementation(libs.vaadin) {
    exclude group: 'com.vaadin', module: 'vaadin-board-flow'
    exclude group: 'com.vaadin', module: 'vaadin-charts-flow'
    exclude group: 'com.vaadin', module: 'vaadin-cookie-consent-flow'
    exclude group: 'com.vaadin', module: 'vaadin-crud-flow'
    exclude group: 'com.vaadin', module: 'vaadin-grid-pro-flow'
    exclude group: 'com.vaadin', module: 'vaadin-map-flow'
    exclude group: 'com.vaadin', module: 'vaadin-rich-text-editor-flow'
}
```